# how to read the "?" operator

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to read this code. what is the equivalent code with if/else statements?

```
            leftPanel.getLayoutParams().width = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetWidth * interpolatedTime);
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java

Comment: You didn't try to search very hard it seems.

Comment: Simply: `boolean expression ? value if true : value if false`

Comment: This is a ternary operator syntax in java and it says...

1. Check if `interpolatedTime == 1`, then assign `leftPanel.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.

2. Else assign `leftPanel.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(targetWidth * interpolatedTime)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) and is exactly equivalent to:

```
if(interpolatedTime == 1) {
    leftPanel.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
} else {
   leftPanel.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(targetWidth * interpolatedTime);
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html for the Oracle documentation for it.